# Why does my code in android annotations fail without anything in the logs

Tags: android, rest, annotations, android-annotations

I'm new to android annotations so maybe I'm missing something but I'm basically trying to copy the rest client seen https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest%20API here

Where I have an interceptor defined as follows

```
@EBean(scope = Scope.Singleton)
public class RestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor{

final String TAG = "rest";

@Bean
AuthStore authStore;

@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] data, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
        throws IOException{

    //Need to set the api key here but nothing happens code quits
//        Log.d("Rest",authStore.getSessionKey());

     HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();

     headers.set("api_key",authStore.getApiKey());

     ClientHttpResponse resp = execution.execute(request, data);

     HttpStatus code = resp.getStatusCode();

     Log.d(TAG,resp.getBody().toString());

     if(code.value() == 200){
        Log.d(TAG,"success code 200"); 

     }
     else{
         Log.d(TAG,"fail code" + code.toString());
     }
     return resp;
}
```

}

But the code just quits when I try to add the extra header. The auth store class looks like this

```
@EBean(scope = Scope.Singleton)
 public class AuthStore {

public String apiKey,sessionKey;

public String getApiKey() {
    return apiKey;
}

public void setApiKey(String apiKey) {
    this.apiKey = apiKey;
}

public String getSessionKey() {
    return sessionKey;
}

public void setSessionKey(String sessionKey) {
    this.sessionKey = sessionKey;
}
```

}

Rest interface

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "https://pathtoapi/rest/public/", converters = {     GsonHttpMessageConverter.class }, interceptors = {RestInterceptor.class })
public interface ApiClient {

@Get("force_login")
ApiSession forceLogin();

// if you need to add some configuration to the Spring RestTemplate.
RestTemplate getRestTemplate();

void setRestTemplate(RestTemplate restTemplate);
```

}

Comment: try catching the exception and calling `e.printStackTrace()` on it.

Comment: No exception is thrown that's why its so weird

Comment: when you say ` just quits` what do you mean? It force closes?

Comment: No it doesn't quit or freeze it just stops executing the code. If I comment out the header.set method it will run fine